# Upper Bound of a Set rationals

Tags: real-analysis

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, I looked up similar questions but I couldn't find anything that answered my question. I'm studying real analysis all over again and I'm trying to prove that the set $S = \{r\in \mathbb{Q}\mid r^2<\sqrt{2}\}$ has no supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$. I make the claim that $\sqrt{2}$ is an upper bound of $S$.

My question is, is the upper bound of a set defined relative to a superset of the set in question? In this case, is it sound to say that $\sqrt{2}$ is an upper bound of a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes it is relative, hence no it is not sound. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: Thank you so much